# do while statments with if

Tags: java

consider the following code snippet:

```
           String msg = null;
            do {
                msg = login();
            } while (!msg.equals("OK"));
```

I want to display a message in the console when `msg` is different from`"OK"`, 
for example: `ERROR, Try again...!`. I did this:

```
        String msg;
        do {
            msg = login();
            if(!msg.equals("OK")){
                System.out.println("ERROR, Try again...!");
            }
        } while (!msg.equals("OK"));
```

It works. I wonder if there is another elegant ways to do it.

Comment: Looks fine to me...

Comment: Do...whiles are a fairly standard way of achieving this. When I need to do validation like this, I extract the loop into its own function, and have it accept a predicate that verifies the input. In your case, the predicate would be `!msg.equals("OK")`. That way if you need to do any other validation, you dont need to have bulky loops all over the place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String msg;
while (!(msg = login()).equals("OK")) {
    System.out.println("ERROR, Try again...!");
}
```

or even

```
while (!login().equals("OK")) {
    System.out.println("ERROR, Try again...!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can **edit** your code with the following:

```
while (!login().equals("OK")) {
    System.out.println("ERROR, Try again...!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to break the loop instead of using the condition clause. This lets you avoid the duplicated check:

```
String msg;
do {
    msg = login();
    if (msg.equals("OK")) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("ERROR, Try again...!");
} while (true);
```